# aws s3 iam user vs signed urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need to allow my users to access and upload content to AWS S3.

Now I have two decisions to make:

1. Create a separate bucket for each user or store data for each user in different directories in a single bucket.
2. Allow them access via signed url or create a separate IAM user for everyone?

   The process needs to be fully automated and scalable (i.e. many users sign up or stop using the services every day).

Each user uploads files every few seconds. I therefore thought that a separate IAM user would save me the roundtrip to get a signed URL, but I am not sure if it is practical to have potentially thousands of IAM users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have 100 buckets per AWS account, total not per region so you shouldn't create a bucket per user.

Use keys (folders) to organise the data. Provide access via signed cookies (or urls, but cookies are better for per user) and do the authentication in your application (or use AWS Cognito). IAM isn't really designed for your application end users but for AWS service users.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html

Comment: This was what I thought in the first place. However your hint on AWS Cognito seems to be the perfect fit for my needs. I'll look into that. Thank you

Comment: The limit of 100 buckets is now only the *default* limit -- you can now present your use case to AWS support and request an increase... but a bucket per user is still not a good idea. +1

Comment: Good to know about the buckets, I assume they've got per region fqdn now like some other services (Beanstalk/ELB) so can afford to.